# replace a given value within a column with the next different number in a row in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set that will ultimately be about ~30,000 observations. I have formatted a variable in such a way that the numerical values 1:4 are of interest, while the value 5 is a place holder and was not able to be collected by our testing instrument for one reason or another (not worried about why or missingness etc).

I am looking to turn any observation of 5, or series of observations of 5, into the next number in the observations. As can be seen in the example data set below, the first four observations have the number 5 while the next four observations are the number 4. In this situation I would like the first 4 observations to be changed from 5 to 4.

Note that after the 8th observation another series of 5's occur, follow by a series of 3s. In this case the 5s should be changed to 3s.

In the code block below I have provided an example of what the current data look like, delineated by the column "Current." I have also provided a column of the desired output, delineated by the column name "Desired." The obs variable was helpful to create just to show the row number of the changes in values for the case of this post.

```
df <- data.frame(Current = c(5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,3,3,3,5,3,3,5,5,2,5,5,5,1),
                 Desired = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1))

df$obs = seq(1,nrow(df), by = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_column = na_if(Current, 5)) %>% 
  fill(new_column, .direction = "up")
```

This returns

```r
   Current Desired new_column
1        5       4          4
2        5       4          4
3        5       4          4
4        5       4          4
5        4       4          4
6        4       4          4
7        4       4          4
8        4       4          4
9        5       3          3
10       5       3          3
11       3       3          3
12       3       3          3
13       3       3          3
14       5       3          3
15       3       3          3
16       3       3          3
17       5       2          2
18       5       2          2
19       2       2          2
20       5       1          1
21       5       1          1
22       5       1          1
23       1       1          1
```

- We use `dplyr`'s `na_if` function to convert the `5` into missing values.
- Next we use `tidyr`'s `fill` function to replace the `NA`'s by the following values.

Comment: Martiiiin, how are you? glad to see you here bro :D

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Very fine. Work's done for this year, now it's just relaxing, getting boostered (tomorrow) and some sleep. But the Advent of Code complicates the _sleep_ part. ;-) What's up to you?

Comment: Great to hear that everything is fine with you. Offf I am also doing fine but been through a lot with university. Did a lots of R coding in TS forecasting last period and I am going to continue with my thesis in that section. I plan on starting Python during Christmas. By the way Merry Christmas to you and your family my friend :)

Comment: The same to you and your beloved ones, dear @AnoushiravanR. Python is worth a look, very powerful tool, but R works better for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yeah it's also difficult for me to shift to Python, but I think I will need it for my future job in this area. Still much to learn about R.

Comment: Both of these responses are great. And response time on both your parts was great!  Both solve the problem :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution. I made use of `zoo::na.locf` function which takes the most non-NA value and replace all `NA`s on the way down. However, to fit this to your data set I first replaced all values equal to `5` with `NA` and then reverse the vector and after I replaced all the values with the desired values, I again reversed it back to its original order:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(Desired2 = ifelse(Current == 5, NA, Current), 
         Desired2 = rev(na.locf(rev(Desired2))))

   Current Desired Desired2
1        5       4        4
2        5       4        4
3        5       4        4
4        5       4        4
5        4       4        4
6        4       4        4
7        4       4        4
8        4       4        4
9        5       3        3
10       5       3        3
11       3       3        3
12       3       3        3
13       3       3        3
14       5       3        3
15       3       3        3
16       3       3        3
17       5       2        2
18       5       2        2
19       2       2        2
20       5       1        1
21       5       1        1
22       5       1        1
23       1       1        1
```